# How to insert operation through WCF Service with MYSQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wcf

I try to create a insert operation through WCF Service. Here is what i have done. First of all i will show you my project structure

[image: project structure]

Each file explanation :

`IServiceClient.cs` contain, group of Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceClient
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InsertMaster();
}
```

`Service.cs` contain group of Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class Service
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id;
    [DataMember]
    public string Submitter;
    [DataMember]
    public string Comments;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TimeSubmitted;
}
```

`ServiceClient.cs` contain, business logic like Insert to MYSQL operation

```
public void InsertMaster()
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO movies (id, submitter, comments, time) VALUES(id, submitter, comments, time)";
    //open connection
    connection.Open();
    //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    //Execute command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //close connection
    connection.Close();
}
```

and my problem is, how to pass Data Contract field to ServiceClient.cs so i can write some MYSQL query? that "string query" is just my demo that i want to insert from the value that give by data contract

and my second problem is how to load data contract field into WCF Test Client? i need to test it about to work or not before i do use it in my Client side project

Comment: public void InsertMaster(Service data) and the same on OperationContract void InsertMaster(Service data);

Comment: Why not have your data contract accept the Service type, implement that in the ServiceClient Class.  Then when you run that in your WCF Test Client You should be able to fill out the Service Class type with its data and submit it, if not you can always copy the request XML from the XML tab at the bottom, then use a program like PostMan in Chrome to fill your data out and post it to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you need to modify :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceClient
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InsertMaster(Service ServiceObj);
}

[DataContract]
public class Service
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id;
    [DataMember]
    public string Submitter;
    [DataMember]
    public string Comments;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TimeSubmitted;
}

public void InsertMaster(Service ServiceObj)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO movies (id, submitter, comments, time) VALUES(ServiceObj.id, ServiceObj.submitter, ServiceObj.comments, ServiceObj.time)";
    //open connection
    connection.Open();
    //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    //Execute command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //close connection
    connection.Close();

}
```

Contract will appear once you test using WCF test client.